# swap User Control from selected item from combo box

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I am creating a windows form in vb.
My image below is crude, but what I'm trying to pull off is this:

I have created 3 User Controls
I have a main form with a combobox, the combobox has three selections "User Control 1, User Control 3 and User Control 3. 
I want to be able to dynamically display one of my 3 User Controls into a Panel based on whichever item is selected from the combobox. 
The picture example shows User Control 3 selected in the Panel below the combobox because it is selected from the drop down box.

Can anyone point me to an example tutorial of this?
Thanks!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxLVq.png)

Comment: Use the .Visible property on the controls with the Selected changed events

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: Please read [ask] and take the [tour].  Questions asking for offsite resources like tutorials are OT

Comment: Do you have one panel ***or*** a panel for each `UserControl`? As mentioned already above, you would use the `SelectedChanged` event from the `ComboBox` to fire off when a user changes the `SelectedItem`, there you can grab your value and then show what `UserControl` you would like. Please show us what you have tried and where you are stuck and then we can help you.

Comment: I ended up going with panels and using the Visible option. Thanks everyone for looking!